# BQ Ubuntu phone: Did you have to calibrate your battery?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, battery, bq

I'm happy with the battery life of my phone, I get several days of use between charges. The problem is that the battery indicator is too unreliable. The charge might drop from [50% to 0%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WK08N.jpg) overnight without the phone being used.

I've contacted BQ support and they told me to calibrate my battery. I'm going to do as they say, however I have a feeling that won't do the trick. I used to have an Archos Android phone in the past with the same problem that never recovered after months of full charge/recharge cycles...

Has anybody experienced similar issues?

Comment: Last time  mine went from 20% to 0 in less than 2 minutes, so you're not the only one. Could you tell me what is the procedure for calibrating the battery, so I can try it as well?

Comment: I see. And 50% to 0% is just an example, I have also experienced a 70% to 0%.

Comment: @SledgeHammer oops... sorry, I just noticed the second part of your comment! The procedure for calibrating the battery is, and I quote: *Basically, use it until it turns itself off.  Ignore any low battery alerts that may appear.  Then, recharge the battery without any interruptions until it is fully charged to 100%. Verify  the battery indicates a 100% both turned on and off.* You have to do that 3-4 times.

Comment: Thanks, I've already done it once but had no idea it had to be done a few times.

Comment: Askubuntu is not the right site to discuss this. I flagged this question to be removed.

Comment: @Galgalesh Care to say why? Because the only thing you have accomplished with your comment so far (here AND on reddit) is to prevent other people from answering a legit question. This post is about a very real ubuntu issue for which I provide a solution and ask others to share their experience. What part of this post is off-topic according to you? If you want to flag a question, by all means, do it. But don't bully other people, it's not nice.

Comment: Your question is currently "has anyone experienced similar issues?". This is not a question suited for askubuntu because it is to vague, is about personal experience and is therefore unanswerable because it as a discussion, not a question.

Comment: If you want to know how to do that, ask 'how do I do that?'. That is a legit question. If you want to share your knowledge about this issue, ask a self-answered question.

Comment: You can always edit your question to make it comply to askubuntu's policies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BQ Aquaris phone manual states that you should use the phone and completely drain the (pre-charged) battery.  Afterwards you should completely charge and drain the battery the first few times to allow for automatic battery calibration.

If you didn't follow that procedure, I'm not surprised you need to calibrate your battery afterwards.  (This is best practice on any Li+ battery)

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  **;-)**

Comment: I had no idea I was supposed to follow that procedure. But nevertheless, that's exactly what I did.